# How to Read Contents of Localizable.strings and Put it To UIWebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, localizable.strings

In my app, I have a text file that contains something like this:

```
<html>
    <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #333333;
            padding: 14px;
            text-align: justify;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <p>
        This is the first statement.
        <br>
        This is the second statement.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

This data will be loaded to a UIWebView and everything is working. However, I want the texts to be localizable so I'm thinking of putting them to Localizable.strings. And so, Localizable.strings has something like this:

```
FIRST_STATEMENT = "This is the first statement";
SECOND_STATEMENT = "This is the second statement";
```

Now, the question is, how I'm going to access the data from Localizable.strings so that I can put them to the contents of the UIWebView object? I'm thinking of javascript but I'm not sure how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try making a html file Template and put

> %@

at the Places/Tags where u wanna have localize strings and then put the template file in the App Bundle/Documents Dir and use this-

> NSString *anHtmlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"templateFile"
>   ofType:@"html"];//if the file is in App Bundle else use
>
> //NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
>   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
>
> anHtmlStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:anHtmlStr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
>
> anHtmlStr = [NSString
>   stringWithFormat:anHtmlStr,NSLocalizedString(@"key", @"comment")];
>
> [webView loadHTMLString:anHtmlStr baseURL:baseURL];

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working with xcode and objective-c, judging by the UIWebView. You can do it like this:

```
// message body
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"<body>"
            "<p>"
            "%@" // first statement.
            "<br />"
            "%@" // second statement
            "<br />"
            "%d" // some integer value
            "</p>"
            "</body>",
            NSLocalizedString(@"This is the first statement.", nil),
            NSLocalizedString(@"This is the second statement.", nil),
            intSomeValue];
```

You can split the string over multiple lines. Btw if you have lots of text then you really need the comments lines to keep track of which %@ means what string-replace value.